# Python interpreter as a c++ class

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, python-c-api, python-embedding

I am working on embedding python in to c++. In some peculiar case I require two separate instances of the interpreter in same thread.

Can I wrap Python interpreter in to a c++ class and get services from two or more class instances?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have used Py_NewInterpreter for different interpreters in different threads, but this should also work for several interpreters within one thread:

In the main thread:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyEval_InitThreads();
mainThreadState = PyEval_SaveThread();
```

For each interpreter instance (in any thread):

```
// initialize interpreter
PyEval_AcquireLock();                // get the GIL
myThreadState = Py_NewInterpreter();
... // call python code
PyEval_ReleaseThread(myThreadState); // swap out thread state + release the GIL

... // any other code

// continue with interpreter
PyEval_AcquireThread(myThreadState); // get GIL + swap in thread state
... // call python code
PyEval_ReleaseThread(myThreadState);

... // any other code

// finish with interpreter
PyEval_AcquireThread(myThreadState);
... // call python code
Py_EndInterpreter(myThreadState);
PyEval_ReleaseLock();                // release the GIL
```

Note that you need a variable myThreadState for each interpreter instance!

Finally the finish in the main thread:

```
PyEval_RestoreThread(mainThreadState);
Py_Finalize();
```

There are some restrictions with using several interpreter instances (they seem not to be totally independent), but in most cases this does not seem to cause problems.

Answer (score 6):

Callin `Py_Initialize()` twice won't work well, however [`Py_NewInterpreter`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#Py_NewInterpreter) can work, depending on what you're trying to do. Read the docs carefully, you have to hold the GIL when calling this.

Comment: I guess I will not get a straightforward answer to my question. Your answer has given me some inputs on which I can start work. Py_NewInterpreter seems to be the correct option to start exploring the scenario I have described. Based on this I am accepting your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but I'd recommend you not to re-implement a Python interpreter when there is a standard implementation. Use **boost::python** to interface with Python.

Comment: boost python uses python c apis. is it possible to start the interpreter twice by calling Py_Initialize()?

Answer (score 2):

mosaik's answer did not work in my situation where my module is a plugin to a host application that already initializes python. I was able to get it to work with the following code.

```
// initialize interpreter
::PyEval_InitThreads();
::PyThreadState *mainThread = ::PyThreadState_Get();
myState = ::Py_NewInterpreter();
... // call python code
::PyThreadState_Swap(mainThread);

... // any other code

mainThread = ::PyThreadState_Swap(myState)
... // call python code
::PyThreadState_Swap(mainThread)

... // any other code

// finished with interpreter
mainThread = ::PyThreadState_Swap(myState)
::Py_EndInterpreter(myState);
::PyThreadState_Swap(mainThread)
```

When I called `PyEval_AcquireLock()` the program blocked and the function did not return. Further, calling `PyEval_ReleaseThread(myState)` seemed to invalidate the interpreter also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are the first person to want to do this, unfortunately I believe it is not possible. Are you able to run the python interperters as separate processes and use RPC?

Answer (score 0):

- You can let the python interpreter live outside of your application memory space. Just embed the interpreter in a DLL.
- You can set up & save python contexts to simulate two different interpreters.