# boost python, using a namespace other than main global

Tags: c++, namespaces, boost-python, python-embedding

I am embedding python in my C++ application using boost python. I am a C++ programmer, with very limited knowledge of Python.

I have a C++ class, `PyExpression`. Each instance of this class has a string `expStr`, which is a short user-entered (at runtime) python program, that is executed by calling `boost::python::exec`. Briefly, I have this set up as:

```
//import main and its globals
bp::object main = bp::import("__main__");
bp::object main_namespace = main.attr("__dict__");
```

where `main` and `main_namespace` are members of the C++ class `PyExpression`.

```
void PyExpression::Run()
{
    bp::object pyrun = exec(expStr,main_namespace);
}
```

The problem here is that different C++ instances of `PyExpression` modify the same global python namespace, `main_namespace`, and I want each `PyExpression` instance to have its own "global" namespace.

If I pass in `boost::python::dict class_dict` instead of `main_namespace` above, it works at a basic level. But if `PyExpression::expStr` imports a module, e.g. `import sys`, then I get an `ImportError`. Also, using `class_dict`, I can no longer call `globals()`, `locals()`, `vars()`, as they all become undefined.

I have also tried exposing `PyExpression` as a python module. Briefly,

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyExpModule)
{
    bp::class_<PyExpression>("PyExpression", bp::no_init)
    //a couple .def functions
}

int pyImport = PyImport_AppendInittab( "PyExpModule", &initPyExpModule );

bp::object thisExpModule = bp::object( (bp::handle<>(PyImport_ImportModule("PyExpModule"))) );
bp::object PyExp_namespace = thisExpModule.attr("__dict__");
```

Unfortunately, using `PyExp_namespace`, again I get the ImportError when the string to be executed imports a python module, and again, the namespace is shared between all instances of `PyExpression`.

In short, I want to be able to use a namespace object/dictionary, that is preferably a class member of `PyExpression`, have only that instance of `PyExpression` have access to the namespace, and the namespace to act like a global namespace such that other modules can be imported, and the `globals(), locals(), vars() are all defined.

If anyone can point me to a sketch of working code, I would very much appreciate it. I can't find relevant material on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before providing a solution, I want to provide some clarification on Python behavior.

Boost.Python's `object` is essentially a higher-level handle of a smart pointer.  Thus, multiple `object` instances may point to the same Python object.

```cpp
object main_module = import("__main__");
object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
```

The above code imports a module named `__main__`.  In Python, modules are essentially singletons due to the [import behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement).   Therefore, although the C++ `main_module` may be a member of the C++ `PyExpression` class, they all point to the same Python `__main__` module, as it is a singleton.   This results in `main_namespace` pointing to the same namespace.

Much of Python is built around dictionaries.  For example, with an `example` module:

```python
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 42;

    def bar(self):
        pass
```

There are 3 dictionaries of interests:

- `example.__dict__` is the `example` module's namespace.

  ```python
  >>> example.__dict__.keys()
  ['__builtins__', '__file__', '__package__', '__name__', 'Foo', '__doc__']
  ```
- `example.Foo.__dict__` is a dictionary that describes the `Foo` class.  Additionally, it would contain the equivalent of C++'s static member variables and functions.

  ```python
  >>> example.Foo.__dict__.keys()
  ['__module__', 'bar', '__doc__', '__init__']
  ```
- `example.Foo().__dict__` is a dictionary containing instance-specific variables.  This would contain the equivalent of C++'s non-static member variables.

  ```python
  >>> example.Foo().__dict__.keys()
  ['x']
  ```

The Python [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) statement takes two optional arguments:

- The first argument specifies the dictionary that will be used for `globals()`.  If the second argument is omitted, then it is also used for `locals()`.
- The second argument specifies the dictionary that will be used for `locals()`.  Variable changes occurring within `exec` are applied to `locals()`.

To get the desired behavior, `example.Foo().__dict__` needs to be used as `locals()`.  Unfortunately, this becomes slightly more complicated because of the following two factors:

- Although `import` is a Python keyword, the CPython implementation is dependent on `__builtins__.__import__`.  Thus, there needs to be a guarantee that the `__builtin__` module is assessable as `__builtins__` within the namespace passed to `exec`.
- If a C++ class called `Foo` is exposed as a Python class through Boost.Python, then there is no easy way to access the Python `Foo` instance from within the C++ `Foo` instance.

To account for these behaviors, the C++ code will need to:

- Get a handle to the Python object's `__dict__`.
- Inject the `__builtin__` module into the Python object's `__dict__`.
- Extract the C++ object from the Python object.
- Pass the Python object's `__dict__` to the C++ object.

---

Here is an example solution that only sets variables on the instance for which code is being evaluated:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class PyExpression
{
public:
  void run(boost::python::object dict) const
  {
    exec(exp_.c_str(), dict);
  }
  std::string exp_;
};

void PyExpression_run(boost::python::object self)
{
  // Get a handle to the Python object's __dict__.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object self_dict = self.attr("__dict__");

  // Inject the __builtin__ module into the Python object's __dict__.
  self_dict["__builtins__"] = python::import("__builtin__");

  // Extract the C++ object from the Python object.
  PyExpression& py_expression = boost::python::extract<PyExpression&>(self);

  // Pass the Python object's `__dict__` to the C++ object.
  py_expression.run(self_dict);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyExpModule)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<PyExpression>("PyExpression")
    .def("run", &PyExpression_run)
    .add_property("exp", &PyExpression::exp_, &PyExpression::exp_)
    ;
}

// Helper function to check if an object has an attribute.
bool hasattr(const boost::python::object& obj,
             const std::string& name)
{
  return PyObject_HasAttrString(obj.ptr(), name.c_str());
}

int main()
{
  PyImport_AppendInittab("PyExpModule", &initPyExpModule);
  Py_Initialize();

  namespace python = boost::python;
  try
  {
    // python: import PyExpModule
    python::object py_exp_module = python::import("PyExpModule");

    // python: exp1 = PyExpModule.PyExpression()
    // python: exp1.exp = "import time; x = time.localtime().tm_year"
    python::object exp1 = py_exp_module.attr("PyExpression")();
    exp1.attr("exp") = 
      "import time;"
      "x = time.localtime().tm_year"
      ;

    // python: exp2 = PyExpModule.PyExpression()
    // python: exp2.exp = "import time; x = time.localtime().tm_mon"
    python::object exp2 = py_exp_module.attr("PyExpression")();
    exp2.attr("exp") = 
      "import time;"
      "x = time.localtime().tm_mon"
      ;

    // Verify neither exp1 nor exp2 has an x variable.
    assert(!hasattr(exp1, "x"));
    assert(!hasattr(exp2, "x"));

    // python: exp1.run()
    // python: exp2.run()
    exp1.attr("run")();
    exp2.attr("run")();

    // Verify exp1 and exp2 contain an x variable.
    assert(hasattr(exp1, "x"));
    assert(hasattr(exp2, "x"));

    // python: print exp1.x
    // python: print exp2.x
    std::cout << python::extract<int>(exp1.attr("x")) 
      << "\n" << python::extract<int>(exp2.attr("x"))
      << std::endl;
  }
  catch (python::error_already_set&)
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
[twsansbury@localhost]$ ./a.out 
2013
5
```

Due to how libraries are loaded from imports, it may require providing arguments to the linker that will cause all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table.  For example, when compiling the above example with gcc, using `-rdynamic` was required.  Otherwise, `import time` will fail due to an undefined `PyExc_IOError` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not provide a 100% reliable isolation mechanism for this kind of task. That said, the essential tool you are looking for is the Python C-API `Py_NewInterpreter`, which is [documented here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_NewInterpreter). You will have to call it upon the creation of your `PyExpression` object, to create a new (semi)-isolated environment (N.B.: the destructor should call `Py_EndInterpreter`).

This is untested, but I'd guess something liket this would do the job:

```
PyThreadState* current_interpreter = Py_NewInterpreter();
bp::object pyrun = exec(expStr);
Py_EndInterpreter(current_interpreter);
```

You may wrap that into an object. If you wish to do so, you **must** manage the "thread" state as explained [in this other stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480490/python-interpreter-as-a-c-class).